# wp_schedule_single_event issue with save_post hook in gutenberg

Tags: block-editor, wp-cron, save-post

I am using the "save_post" hook to call `wp_schedule_single_event`.  Everything works as expected with the classic editor, however when I try a post in gutenberg there isn't actually a cron entry that is getting created.  I know it's still calling the hook since it's updating some post meta values.  Any ideas why the cron entry is not saving with the `wp_schedule_single_event` call?

Comment: Have you tried this solution https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_schedule_single_event-does-not-call-my-action/?

Comment: Not sure how that is relevant?  It's currently running from a plugin - and it works 100% correctly with the classic editor.  The issue only happens with the block-editor / gutenberg editor.